# Passing a variable to a (globally?) exported class

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I apologize if this question doesn't really make sense - I'm probably lacking a bit of an understanding on how exactly `module.export` works and scoping between classes, but I will try my best to explain. I currently have a discord bot with a music player that has a `MusicPlayer` class - this class is exported in this manner:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord');
const MusicQueue = require('./musicqueue');
const discordUtils = require ('../../../utils/discord-utils');

class MusicPlayer {
    constructor() {
        this.repeat_playlist = false;
        this.queue = new MusicQueue(); // this is the persistent queue for the server
        this.dispatcher = null;
        this.volume = 1; 
        this.stopped = true;
        this.paused = false;
        this.repeat_current_song = false;
        this.auto_delete = false;
        this.manual_index = false;
        this.autodcEnabled = false;
    }

    ....
}

module.exports = new MusicPlayer();
```

I have various music-related commands that import this music player like so:

```
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const discordUtils = require ('../../utils/discord-utils');
let musicplayer = require(`./modules/musicplayer`);

module.exports = class TestCommand extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

My question is, how would I pass a local variable to the `musicplayer` constructor since I'm exporting it via `module.exports = new MusicPlayer();`?

It's my understanding that using `module.exports = new MusicPlayer();` would allow me to use the same `musicplayer` object throughout the entire project (which is what I want); but - and this is where I'm not sure I understand how `module.exports` works - there's no guarantee when (if at all) the `musicplayer` will be instantiated.

If you never use a music-related command the `musicplayer` will never be created because `let musicplayer = require('./modules/musicplayer');` will never be run, right?

Either way, now I need to pass something to the `musicplayer` constructor from within one of the commands, how can I do so in a way that I don't have to repeatedly do something like: `let musicplayer = require('./modules/musicplayer')(variable);` in *every* file that requires the music player? Is there a way for me to declare `let musicplayer = require('./modules/musicplayer')(variable);` one time and have that `musicplayer` be used throughout the entire codebase?

Comment: Could you instead export the Class "module.exports = MusicPlayer;"? Then you have more flexibility. And then instantiate the singleton at startup when you have all needed information.

Comment: Can you make sure that the file that has the initialization variable for the constructor, loads the music player first before anyone else who wants to use the music player?  That would make things easier.  Can you put that early in your app's startup sequence?

Comment: Does the music player singleton have to come directly from the music player module or can it come from your `app` object or from the import of some other module?  There are many ways to solve this so I'm just trying to frame what the constraints are.

Comment: I had considered doing that and it shouldn't be a problem, I was just wondering if there was a way to go about it in some other way that I had probably missed. I mainly did it the way I had because I figured it could save on memory if there were people who didn't _need_ the music player, it wouldn't needlessly create it and take up space - as written now it only creates one when a user tries to use a music-related command.

Comment: Well, who has this initialization variable?  Where does it come from?   That's the key to what your options are here.  You can still create the player upon demand, but that code has to go through whoever has the initialization variable.

Comment: Apologies if I'm a bit slow on the uptake, I'm still fairly new to js and I'm trying to make sense of all this. If I follow what you're saying, it looks like you mean: `module.exports = new MusicPlayer();` right? By exporting it in that way, whenever I called `require('./modules/musicplayer')` it would initialize the music player and I could just use it in that one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's list out a few requirements:

1. You want to share a single music player among a bunch of code.
2. You want the music player to be created upon demand, only when someone actually needs it
3. You want to initialize the music player with some variable you have in your code

To make this work, you have to centralize the creation of the music player and that has to be coordinated with whoever has the initialization variable that you want to pass to the constructor.  There are many ways to do that.  I will illustrate two of them.

Let's assume that it's your application initialization code that has this variable that you want to use when creating the music player.  So, rather than having everyone load the music player module themselves, we will have them all ask the app for the music player.

```
// app.js
const MusicPlayer = require(`./modules/musicplayer`);    // load module to get constructor

let musicPlayerInitVariable;    // your code sets this during startup


const sharedPlayer;
function getMusicPlayer() {
    if (!sharedPlayer) {
         sharedPlayer = new MusicPlayer(musicPlayerInitVariable);
    }
    return sharedPlayer;

}

// one of many possible exports from your app
module.exports = { getMusicPlayer };
```

Then, in any of your application files that want access to the shared music player, then just do this:

```
const musicPlayer = require('./app.js').getMusicPlayer();
```

This requires that anyone using the shared musicPlayer knows how to reference app.js.

---

Another way to do it is to have your app, initialize the music player module itself with some initial state that it can then use when it creates the music player upon demand.

```
// musicplayer.js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord');
const MusicQueue = require('./musicqueue');
const discordUtils = require ('../../../utils/discord-utils');

class MusicPlayer {
    constructor() {
        this.repeat_playlist = false;
        this.queue = new MusicQueue(); // this is the persistent queue for the server
        this.dispatcher = null;
        this.volume = 1; 
        this.stopped = true;
        this.paused = false;
        this.repeat_current_song = false;
        this.auto_delete = false;
        this.manual_index = false;
        this.autodcEnabled = false;
    }

    ....
}

// this is the constructor variable
// You can either give it a default value so things will work if the player
// is not configured or if you don't give it a default value, then the code
// will require that configurePlayer() is called first
let musicPlayerInitVariable;

// call this before anyone calls getMusicPlayer()
function configurePlayer(data) {
    // save this for later
    musicPlayerInitVariable = data;
}

let sharedPlayer;

function getMusicPlayer() {
    if (!sharedPlayer) {
       if (!musicPlayerInitVariable) {
           throw new Error('Music player must be configured with configurePlayer() first')
       }
       sharedPlayer = new MusicPlayer(musicPlayerInitVariable);
    }
    return sharedPlayer;
}

module.exports = { getMusicPlayer, configurePlayer };
```

Then, in your app-startup code somewhere, you do this:

```
require('./modules/musicplayer').configurePlayer(passMagicVariableHere);
```

From then on, anyone can just do:

```
const musicPlayer = require('./modules/musicplayer').getMusicPlayer();
```

Comment: Both of these are pretty much what I was looking for. Seeing the full examples laid out, everything makes a lot more sense now, I'll go ahead and accept this as the answer, thanks a lot!